# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument iam_api_key

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I am getting the errors in Flask of "TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'iam_api_key'". Actually, it was working fine with Python 2.7 and 3 before installing Flask. But, now it is not working with Python 3 after Flask installation. But, still working using Python 2.

```
    from flask import Flask
from os.path import join, dirname
import json
app = Flask(__name__)
from watson_developer_cloud import SpeechToTextV1
@app.route('/',['GET'])

def hello_world():
    url="https://gateway-wdc.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api"
    iam_api_key="IkhuCl3jbYWRJ3QV623PzX6e8715iCV6mbPA7evrD3qYHyS"
    speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(url=url,iam_api_key=iam_api_key)
    print (speech_to_text)
    return 'Hello, World!'
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)
```

Comment: I am using the Python 3.6.5

Comment: I hope that API key isn't real. You might want to remove that...

Comment: It is not real some characters are added in this key.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `iam_api_key` has been renamed to `iam_apikey` in version 1.7.1. There is some discussion at this [Github issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/issues/520).